# JS detectNetwork Coding Exercise

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble trying to solve the following JavaScript coding exercise.

> Write the function detectNetwork. It should accept a string or a
>   number for its cardNumber argument, and should return the appropriate
>   network string (or undefined if there's no match), based on the
>   provided cardData.

What I'm struggling to figure out is how to write this function without hardcoding every behavior of the cardData array. I want to effectively use the cardData array as an argument of the function, but have no idea how to.

```js
var cardData = [{
  network: 'Visa',       // card issuer (network)
  prefixes: ['4'],  // beginning digits
  lengths: [13, 16, 19]  // lengths of card numbers
},{
  network: 'Mastercard',
  prefixes: ['51', '52', '53', '54', '55'],
  lengths: [16]
},{
  network: 'American Express',
  prefixes: ['34', '37'],
  lengths: [15]
},{
  network: 'Diner\'s Club',
  prefixes: ['38', '39'],
  lengths: [14]
}];

function detectNetwork(cardNumber, cardData) {
  // your solution here
}

// example
var network = detectNetwork('343456789012345', cardData);
console.log(network); // --> 'American Express'
```

Comment: Hi Jon! 

StackOverflow isn't a "do my work for me" site.  What have you tried? Anyway, check out the filter function on the Array object...

Comment: I agree with @frandroid that it won't help you develop skills if people give you the full answer. However, sometimes students have difficulty getting all the pieces together to start writing a solution. In such case, some guidance to the approach can help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that works it this particular case)

```js
function detectNetwork(cardNumber, cardData) {
  // your solution here
  if(typeof cardNumber === "number"){
    cardNumber = cardNumber.toString()
  }
  for(let i = 0; i < cardData.length; i++){
    if(cardData[i]['lengths'].includes(cardNumber.length) && cardData[i]['prefixes'].toString() === cardNumber[0]){
      return cardData[i]['issuer/network']; 
    } else if (Number(cardData[i]['lengths'].toString()) === cardNumber.length){
      return cardData[i]['issuer/network'];
      };
  };
  return undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Main idea is first checking the length of card. If we found the element in the array with similar length, we are checking elements in array with prefixes inside this object. If we found similar prefix, returning the name of the network.

```
function detectNetwork(cardNumber, cardData) {
  var answer = '';
  var cardLength = cardNumber.length;
  var firstTwoDigits = cardNumber[0] + cardNumber[1];

  for (var i =0; i < cardData.length; i++){
    var cardObj = cardData[i];
    if (cardObj['lengths'] == cardLength){
      var arrOfPrefixes = cardObj['prefixes'];
      for (var j =0; j < arrOfPrefixes.length; j++){
        if (arrOfPrefixes[j] === firstTwoDigits){
          answer = cardObj['network'];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is

1. compare the cardNumber length with each issuer's lengths
2. if there's a match, find the target prefix length and slice the card number to match it
3. comparing each issuer's prefixes with card number's prefixes using for loop
4. if there's a match, update the issuer

```
function detectNetwork(cardNumber, cardData) {
  if(typeof cardNumber === 'number'){
    cardNumber = cardNumber.toString();
  }

  let cardLength = cardNumber.length;
  let issuer;

  for(let x = 0; x < cardData.length; x ++ ){
    let currentIssueObj = cardData[x];
    let currentIssueLengths = cardData[x].lengths;
    let currentIssuePrefixes = currentIssueObj.prefixes;

    if ( currentIssueLengths.includes(cardLength)) {
      let targetPrefixesLength = findMaxPrefixesLength(currentIssuePrefixes);
      let cardPrefixes = cardNumber.slice(0,targetPrefixesLength);
      for( let index = 0; index < currentIssuePrefixes.length; index ++ ){
        if( cardPrefixes === currentIssuePrefixes[index]) {
          issuer = currentIssueObj['issuer/network'];
          break;
          } 
      }
    }
  }
  return issuer;
}

//helper function 
function findMaxPrefixesLength(arr){
  let maxLength = arr[0].length;
  for(let x = 1; x < arr.length; x ++ ){
    if (arr[x].length > maxLength){
      maxLength = arr[x].length;
    }
  }
  return maxLength;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function detectNetwork(cardNumber, cardData) {

  var output = "";
  var input = String(cardNumber);
  var firstDig = input.slice(0, 1);
  var first2Dig = input.slice(0, 2);
  for(var i = 0; i < cardData.length; i++){
    if(cardData[i].prefixes.includes(firstDig) || cardData[i].prefixes.includes(first2Dig)){
     output += cardData[i]['issuer/network'];
     return output;
   }
   }
  return undefined;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was posed a long time ago, but I saw it on the hack reactor website. If the answer helps anyone then I'm glad.

```
// This function loops over cardData and uses helper functions below to validate if the lengths and prefixes are found in cardNumber.   
function detectNetwork(cardNumber, cardData) {
     for (i = 0; i < cardData.length; i++) {
         let card = cardData[i]
         let cardLengthFound = findLengths(card.lengths)
         let cardPrefixFound = findPrefixes(card.prefixes)
         if(cardLengthFound && cardPrefixFound) {
             return card['issuer/network']
         }
    }
}

// This function checks to see if the prefixes in cardNumber is same as the ones in cardData
function findPrefixes(arr) {
    for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (cardNumber.toString().slice(0, 2).includes(arr[j])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

// This function checks to see if the length in cardNumber is same as the ones in cardData
function findLengths(arr) {
    for (k = 0; k < cardNumber.toString().length; k++) {
        if (cardNumber.toString().length === arr[k]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really liked Max's answer but I don't have enough rep to leave a comment under his post. I pretty much refactored his code because it was easy to understand. Here's my solution:

```
function detectNetwork(cardNumber, cardData) {
// your solution here
var inputCardLength = cardNumber.length;
var inputCardNumbers = cardNumber[0] + cardNumber[1];

for(let counter = 0; counter < cardData.length; counter++){
    let length = cardData[counter]['lengths'];
    let prefix = cardData[counter]['prefixes'];
    let network = cardData[counter]['issuer/network'];

    if((length.includes(inputCardLength)) && (prefix.toString() === inputCardNumbers)) {
        return network;
    } else if(Number(length) === inputCardLength) {
        return network;
    };
  };
  return undefined
};
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is to iterate over the `cardData` array, and then test the values of the `prefixes` and `length` keys against the `cardNumber`, ensuring we cast to either a string or an int, as the question states that `cardNumber` can be either a string or an int.

```html
function detectNetwork(cardNumber, cardData) {
  for(let i = 0, {length} = cardData; i < length; i++){
     if(cardData[i].lengths.some(length => length === cardNumber.length) && cardData[i].prefixes.some(prefix => cardNumber.toString().startsWith(prefix.toString()))){
       return cardData[i].network
     }
  }
}
```

The key parts are the `Array.prototype.some()` and `String.prototype.startsWith()` methods

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Hope this helps - good luck with JS - check out https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvjgXvBlbQiydffZU7m1_aw for a good intro for a new JS programmer :)